# Testing the appartenance to a list

Tags: macros, include

I want to have a command `\myInclude{}` doing the following thing:

- `\myInclude{}` does nothing (if the argument if empty)
- `\myInclude{file.tex}` includes the file named `file.tex` if it has not been previously included (via the command `\myInclude{file.tex}`; otherwise, it does nothing.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution relying on TeX's `\ifcsname`:

```
\newcommand\myIncludeSeen[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname myInclude:#1\endcsname{}%
}
\newcommand\myInclude[1]{%
  \ifcsname myInclude:#1\endcsname
  \else
    \myIncludeSeen{#1}%
    \input{#1}%
  \fi
}
\myIncludeSeen{}
```

Unlike @egreg's solution, it does not append `.tex` automatically, so `\myInclude{file}` and `\myInclude{file.tex}` will be treated as if loading different files.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myIncludeSeen[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname myInclude:#1\endcsname{}%
}
\newcommand\myInclude[1]{%
  \ifcsname myInclude:#1\endcsname
  \else
    \myIncludeSeen{#1}%
    \input{#1}%
  \fi
}
\myIncludeSeen{}

\begin{filecontents*}{colas-a.tex}
This is file A
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{colas-b.tex}
This is file B
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Trying to include A

\myInclude{colas-a}

Trying to include nothing

\myInclude{}

Trying to include B

\myInclude{colas-b}

Trying to include A

\myInclude{colas-a}

Trying to include B

\myInclude{colas-b}

End

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can populate a sequence and check for the filename to be present.

I also add the extension `.tex` if not present (and use `\input` rather than `\include`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myInclude}{m}
 {
  \IfBlankF{#1}{ \colas_myinclude:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \colas_myinclude:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_range:nnn { #1 } { -4 } { -1 } } { .tex }
   {
    \__colas_myinclude:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__colas_myinclude:n { #1.tex }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_colas_myinclude_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__colas_myinclude:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnF \g_colas_myinclude_prop { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_colas_myinclude_prop { #1 }
    \input{#1}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{filecontents*}{colas-a.tex}
This is file A
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{colas-b.tex}
This is file B
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Trying to include A

\myInclude{colas-a}

Trying to include nothing

\myInclude{}

Trying to include B

\myInclude{colas-b.tex}

Trying to include A

\myInclude{colas-a.tex}

Trying to include B

\myInclude{colas-b}

End

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `\IfBlankF` is not recognised. By what can I replace it? I'm sorry but I prefer not to update my LaTeX distribution? My distribution is from 2017.

Comment: Unfortunately, since my distribution is too old, I cannot  use your solution. The command `\str_if_eq:eeTF` is not recognized. Thanks you very much anyway!

Comment: @Colas TL 2017 is definitely too old.